# Delete woocommerce products without featured images

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have more than 1500 products without featured images. I have to delete it. 
I found a query to get list of this products:

```
 select ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key="_thumbnail_id") AND post_type="product"
```

and I found this plugin https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-without-featured-images/ but I can't delete product from it...

both things do the same thing

Can you hint how can I remove these products?

Comment: Did you get all product from this query which have no featured image . @andrej229

Comment: Yes. I have all ID's of these products...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two query... It will be working fine...

Basically these query use only for delete the woocomerce product..

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN(SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key="_thumbnail_id") AND post_type = 'product');

DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID NOT IN (select post_id from wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key="_thumbnail_id") AND post_type = 'product';
```

Comment: After this query stay some 'junk' in the database?

Comment: What kind of junk .. Can you clearly explain it.. I think it would be working fine...  @Andrej229

Comment: Thanks, but: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause Whad do you think about it?

Comment: Its due to relation between both table wp_postmeta and wp_post  and nested subquery.. you can change it as your wish.. First if you want delete product from database.. Then delete all data related to these products.@Andrej229

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand. First I did this query: DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE... But still I can't do the second one. What I need to change to execute it without an error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have take wrong step already dear.. First delete data from wp_postmeta then wp_post @Andrej229

Comment: Yes, unfortunetellt. But I did this and it works fine: DELETE pm
FROM wp_postmeta pm
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE wp.ID IS NULL Thanks!

Comment: Ok... Welcome @Andrej229

Comment: This worked fine for me...

DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE ID NOT IN (select post_id from `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key="_thumbnail_id") AND post_type = "product";

DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` NOT IN( SELECT `ID` FROM `wp_posts` );

Comment: Thanks ... Great job @Joris

Answer (score 4):

I suggest **update** products to **trash status**. In this way, you can use the Wordpress formal mechanism to delete those products.

Based on @kumar-rakesh answer, I used this query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status =  "trash" WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key =  "_thumbnail_id"
)
AND post_type =  'product';
```

I did it with 4500 products and it was successful.

Hope this help!